# Is program worst case O(N)?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, while-loop, big-o

I wrote this piece of code that organizes true and false elements in a boolean array by swapping when the first few elements aren't true elements and vice versa and then it prints the array. Anyway, this is supposed to be a worst case of O(N) where N is the number of elements within the array and I think it is but I'm not really sure.

```
        int l = -1;
        int r = bA.length;
        
        for ( ; ;) {
            while(bA[++l] == true && l < bA.length-1) { }
            while(bA[--r] == false && 0 < r) { }
            if (l < r) {
                bA[l] = true;
                bA[r] = false;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < bA.length; i++) {
            if (i == bA.length - 1) {
                System.out.println(bA[i]);
            } else {
                System.out.print(bA[i]+", ");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you think of an example for `bA` where you algorithm would take more than `n * bA.length` steps?

Comment: Note, that in the *worst case* we read *each* item just *once*: `l` increments only, `r` decrements only and we have `l < r` condition (we stop looping when `l == r`). So we have `O(N)` time complexity, where `N` is a length of `bA` array

Comment: In the _worst_ case every item must be swapped. In the _best_ case items do not need swapping. Either way each item must be accessed and the difference is a constant factor. You have a O(n) == Ω(n) --> Θ(n).